# JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection when using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, connection

I have a java spring application where I use websockets to communicate between the server and angular clients. However, after a certain amount of messages, the server usually can't handle it any longer and produces a `CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection` which ends with: `Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 29999ms.`. The only internal file I can find in the error message is directing to the `save()` method. I build the server using gradle

I run the MySQL server locally using:

XAMPP version 7.1.33

MySQL server version: 10.4.8-MariaDB - Source distribution

Apache webserver 2.4.41

Apache webserver PHP version 7.1.32

phpMyAdmin version 4.9.1

Code where I update entities:

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

entity.setName(object.getString("name"));
entityRepository.save(bord);

entityManager.flush();
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'org.asciidoctor.convert' version '1.5.8'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.name.project'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

ext {
    set('snippetsDir', file("build/generated-snippets"))
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20190722'
    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
}

test {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

asciidoctor {
    inputs.dir snippetsDir
    dependsOn test
}
```

Comment: Have you tried closing the `EntityManager` after use?

Comment: @JensSchauder would that be after commit() or after flush() ? I would assume after commit

Comment: Yes, after commit.

Comment: Your title is misleading. Did you mean that adding WebSocket dependency is causing this? which shouldn't be the case anyways.

Comment: @JensSchauder thank you, this fixed the issue (haven't got an error yet)

Comment: @John I edited the title, thank you

Comment: I made my comment into an answer so the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the `EntityManager` after the commit which means you keeping the connection open and therefore eventually run out of connections.

To fix this close the `EntityManager` after the commit.